# Corda - Deletion of data/states

Tags: bigdata, blockchain, corda

For epcis unpacking event, i eventually had to remove some of reference states to delete parent child relationship. This is one of the use cases that makes it mandatory to delete data.

are there any way how it could be implemented?
what will be cons of it?
is it sufficient to delete data in the SQL database?

Answer (score 1):

There is not any limitation on the deletion of data/states in Corda. But, keep in mind that immutability and provenance are crucial characteristics of Corda.

That means, your future flows will not be able to reach your deleted states.

And it doesn't really matter how you delete your data/states. SQL delete will do.

Comment: how to delete reference states without SQL